# Appium couldn't install the app to real device

Tags: ios, appium

I have updated appium recently, since then I can't get it to work.

- Followings are the errors shows in the appium log"

  1. Error was thrown during the installation process. TypeError
  2. TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
  3. Error: Could not install app: 'The "path" argument must be of type
     string. Received type undefined'
  4. at IOSDeploy.install
     (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/ios-deploy.js:41:13)

When trying to open the inspector session, it only opens the simulator and the inspector window keeps on loading.

DesiredCapabilities:

```
DesiredCapabilities des = new DesiredCapabilities();
    des.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone XS Max");
    des.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "IOS");
    des.setCapability("noReset", true);
    des.setCapability("fullReset", false);
    des.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "00008020-001D650021D8002E");
    des.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.IOS_XCUI_TEST);
    des.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "13.0");
    des.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/Users/isururodrigo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData"
            + "/VisitSingapore-aheghxbadxxzuzardfddwixazzfm/Build/Products/Debug-Staging-iphoneos/VS-Staging.app");
    try {
        driver = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), des);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    driver.setLogLevel(Level.INFO);
```

Appium v1.15.0-1

Node v10.16.3

xcode v11.1

iOS v13.1.2

Comment: try to move you `.app` file to another folder with less length then yours.

Comment: it's an issue with 1.15.0, i had to update it to v1.15.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by updating the v1.15.1, if anyone of you facing this issue update to the latest which is available in this link.

New pre-release is out for v1.15.1: https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.15.1

Comment: You are right, ios-deploy is not working for old appium versions. However, the standalone IOS-DEPLOY binary from brew works fine without issues.